# Can't find Header files when building from console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit, xcodebuild

I have a project which uses a nested project dependency which in my case is [RestKit](http://restkit.org).

### In Xcode

When I build the project from within Xcode RestKit also gets compiled and places its headers here:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproject-blrrqydtywxuereiowkehhhcbozj/Build/Headers
```

The `Header Search Path` value is set accordingly:

```
${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../../Headers
```

### From the Terminal

However, when I build my project from the Terminal I the Headers end up here:

```
~/MyProjectSourceFolder/RestKit/Build/Headers
```

And I get an error during compilation that `RestKit` is not found.

Now how do I get `xcodebuild` to use the same location or the same build environment so that my build also works from the console? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get my script to work the same, when I specify the `-scheme = MyScheme` option.

Comment: I'm running to the exact same thing. I haven't used schemes so I'm wondering how did you set up 'MyScheme' so that command line builds work?

Comment: I didn't explicitly set the scheme, Xcode created it for me and it had the same name as my target. Just go to "Manage Schemes".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to set your preferences to use the legacy build settings.  Go to Preferences->Locations->advanced and select legacy. This will force it to use the Build director for the products both in the UI and the Terminal.

Comment: I can imagine that this works, but shouldn't there be a way to "tell" the console-app to use the non-legacy approach?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way but I had to move on to other things when I got it working ;)  so I haven't really dug into it that much since then.  I'll try out the -scheme option to see if that works for me too.